# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'word_weighting'

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, attributeerror, super

I have a super class `FTM`:

```
class FTM:
    def __init__(self,word_weighting = 'normal'):
        self.word_weighting = word_weighting
    
    def get_sparse_global_term_weights(self, word_weighting):
        pass
```

And a subclass that inherits from `FTM`:

```
class FLSA(FTM):
    def __init__(self, word_weighting='normal'):
        super().__init__(word_weighting = word_weighting)
        self.sparse_global_term_weighting = super().get_sparse_global_term_weights(word_weighting = super().word_weighting)
```

Running this code, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'word_weighting'
```

I have initialized the attribute. Why do I get this error?

Comment: Since you have called `__init__` on super, you should be able to use `self.word_weighting` because it is an instance property.

Comment: Thanks Mark! If you make this the answer, I will upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**super()** only returns a series of ***bound methods*** from the parent class!

Look at this `link`: https://realpython.com/python-super/#a-super-deep-dive

> By including an instantiated object, super() returns a bound method: a
> method that is bound to the object, which gives the method the
> object’s context such as any instance attributes. If this parameter is
> not included, the method returned is just a function, unassociated
> with an object’s context.

**super()** can not return the attributes of a class, and you need to define a property for the "word_weighting".

```
@property
def word_weighting(self):
    return self._word_weighting # attrib: 'word_weighting' was changed it to '_word_weighting'
```